# How can I use PayPal's credit card vault in RoR without having the CC information hit my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I have a client who is dead-set on using PayPal for Credit Card processing.  The application must be able to charge cards without the user entering the information every time.  Digging around, I've found the Credit Card Vault feature, which would at least let me store credit card information for future use.  Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, there's no JS based tokenization procedure in the RoR Paypal SDK gem -- in order to store data in the vault, the information first has to hit my server.  Which means I have to provide PCI compliance.

Is there any way to tokenize a credit card for later use in Paypal that will let the token be valid indefinitely?

Comment: Would be cool if you provided link to documentation inside the question. I looked through it, and there really seems no way to do it in the fronting as either access token or oauth token need to be provided in the request.

Comment: If you were to get a reference payment token for later use, how would you store it on your server without also having to be PCI compliant?

Comment: @davidfurber The reference token isn't a credit card number, and therefore isn't subject to PCI compliance.  So long as we you use SSL to talk to the server, you should be good.

The key here is to use a JS form to hit the Stripe system, and then when it returns you can submit *that* data to your server and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the REST API they call it the vault and they have [documentation specific to it](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#vault).

In the Classic API it's called a reference transaction, in which case you would use Payments Pro ([DoDirectPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/direct-payment/ht_dp-referenceTransactions-curl-etc/) or [PayFlow](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#submitting-reference-transactions---tokenization)) to process an original authorization or sale transaction, and then pass that transaction ID into future calls to process payments with the card data PayPal has saved on their server.

If using DoDirectPayment you would use DoReferenceTransaction.  If using PayFlow you would just change some of the parameters in the typical request to make it a reference transaction.  The doc links above cover all of that.

As long as you aren't saving any card data on your server then the only thing you'll need to be compliant is an SSL certificate on your site, but that's becoming a recommended practice regardless of whether or not you're processing payments.

If you want to completely avoid hitting your server then you'll have to go with [Payments Advanced](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-advanced/), which embeds a PayPal hosted iframe into your site. I don't think it supports reference transactions, though, and it's a lot more limited than REST or Payments Pro.

Comment: I think you're missing a fairly important part, that the REST SDK requires the data to hit our server -- and thus requires PCI compliance on our server.

Comment: I added some more info to the answer.